# Android adb execute permission not being applied

Tags: linux, permissions, android

I tried applying execute permission on adb file but no success.
Here's what I did.

```
root@themanish:/media/BACKUP/AndroidBackup/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools# chmod +x adb
root@themanish:/media/BACKUP/AndroidBackup/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools# ls -l
total 2136
-rw------- 1 themanish themanish 1231255 Jun  6 17:38 adb
drwx------ 1 themanish themanish       0 Jun  6 17:38 api
-rw------- 1 themanish themanish  197710 Jun  6 17:38 fastboot
-rw------- 1 themanish themanish  727881 Jun  6 17:38 NOTICE.txt
-rw------- 1 themanish themanish   16648 Jun  6 17:38 source.properties
drwx------ 1 themanish themanish    4096 Jun  6 17:38 systrace
```

still the permission is -rw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably /media/BACKUP is a FAT or NTFS drive, which is not unix permissions friendly.

Possible solutions:

- Move those files to an ext4 or similar partition
- Format that drive with ext4 or similar filesystem
- Remount forcing execution permissions. If you know the device name XXX:

`sudo umount /media/BACKUP
sudo mount /dev/XXX /media/BACKUP -o exec,umask=000,fmask=000`

Comment: Hey, I didn't notice that thing. I'll give it a try.

Comment: It worked. thanx mate.